# module_invoke/module_invoke_all with multiple arguments

Tags: 7, hooks, emails

I know enough D7 to be dangerous. I'm stumped, however, as to how to call one module from another. In this case, I want to call the simplenews module's subscribe_user hook from a custom module I'm creating. I'm having difficulty passing the multiple arguments either as a string or an array. Here are the variables the hook accepts:

```
$mail = 'test@test.com';
$tid = 1;
$confirm = TRUE;
$source = 'unknown';
$preferred_language = NULL;
```

Can someone please help me call this properly?

```
module_invoke('simplenews', 'subscribe_user', $args);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
simplenews_subscribe_user($mail, $tid, $confirm, $source, $preferred_language);
```

or

```
module_invoke('simplenews', 'subscribe_user', $mail, $tid, $confirm, $source, $preferred_language);
```

module invoke is parsing all given arguements and handles them to the called function.

see php documentation regarding passing variables by reference, if that might bug you someday: http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php#refsect1-function.call-user-func-array-notes